# why is static needed here

Tags: c++, static, static-methods

I am using [curl library](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html) which returns data to me through a callback function with the prototype below

```
size_t write_data(void * data, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void * userpointer);
```

I noticed that if i declare a function fitting this prototype in my class

```
//file Dialog.h
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    private:
    int new_data_callback(void * newdata, size_t size, size_t nmemb, QByteArray * buffer); 
}
```

If i try to use it in my **Dialog.cpp**

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle,CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTIION, new_data_callback);
```

I get an error

```
Invaid use of member (did you forget the '&'?)
```

If i add `static` to my function declaration, it compiles.

```
static int new_data_callback(void * newdata, size_t size, size_t nmemb, QByteArray * buffer); //ok
```

**Question**

Why is static needed in this case?

PS: the classes beginning with Q eg QDialog are part of [QT](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/) and dont affect the question.

Comment: Because non-static member functions have an implicit argument for `this`; i.e. your effective signature looks like `int new_data_callback(Dialog* this, void* newdata, size_t size, size_t nmemb, QByteArray* buffer);`, which is obviously not the signature `curl_easy_setopt` wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a non-static method cannot be called without an instance. Since `new_data_callback` is a callback, the only way to attach an instance to it is through a parameter. Making it `static` removes the instance restriction.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of how functions get invoked. non-static class functions require additional information to be invoked.  Namely the *this* pointer.  When you pass `new_data_callback` to `curl_easy_setopt` this instance specific information is not provided.  Thus,  curl does not have enough information to invoke the function.

If a class function is defined static it, by definition, cannot access non-static members of a class.  Therefore it does not need the additional instance information as above and can be passed to `set_easy_setopt`